# Matching closest image in openCV?

Tags: image, opencv, classification, vision

This is the dilenma I'm having. For my application, I need to match an image **L1** with the matching one **L2** in a set of images. **L1** and **L2** are the exact same image, except **L1** is much smaller (It will need to be upscale?), and could be artifacted a little on the edges, but nevertheless, they are from the exact same source image. Color DOES matter, in that using color information will remove possible ambiguities between the current image and the one it is to be matched with. Using OpenCV (or perhaps there may be a better alternative?), what is the best way to find the matching image (**L2**).

To reiterate, the image to be matched with is not rotated or distorted in anyway, only resized.

I guess there would be a function which rates how close the image to be matched is to all of the images in the set provided. Then we choose the one with the highest rating as the match. I'm not sure as to how to compare the images though. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: if they're really the exact same images (except scaling and some artifacts) I guess first downscaling L2 to the size of L1, the compute `cv::absDiff`. The image with the lowest average pixel difference (L2 norm) should likely be your most similar image in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Go to github and check out opencv-master\samples\cpp\matcher_simple.cpp(or matching_to_many_images.cpp)

not only can it satisfy your need but it also works for images with perspective distortion (eg. rotation, affine transformation and illumination variation). simply put, it's very robust.

but SIFT and SURF are patented, you might not be able to use it for commercial applications, which sucks. but there are many alternatives, just google around!

Comment: If they are patented, you can't even use them for research or open source, unless you have explicit permission from the patent holders. Fortunately; those patents only exist in the US.

Comment: @Nallath I believe you will just have to cite their paper for research purpose. Just do not use their code and buy matlab or something

Comment: That would depend under what licence they released it. They can (if they are so inclined) prevent you from even performing research into that area.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV has [a tutorial on similarity measurement for images](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-input-psnr-ssim/video-input-psnr-ssim.html#videoinputpsnrmssim).

You will need to upscale L1 before doing the comparison, or downscale L2. If you are comparing L2 against lots of images it probably makes more sense to scale L2 down (because you then don't have to call resize for every image being compared against, and there are fewer pixels to be compared).

e.g.

```
cv::Mat L1 = ...;
cv::Mat L2 = ...;

cv::Mat L2small;
cv::resize(L2, L2small, L1.size());
double pnsr = getPSNR(L1, L2small);
// where code for getPSNR() is in the tutorial
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to use something similar to Bag-of-words model used to measure document similarity. Take a look at this: [link](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/def_Gram_matrix.html)

I'm reproducing the equation below:

G = X'*X

where X = [x1 x2 ... xn]

In your case, use the **normalized histogram** of the image as vector xi.

I think you wouldn't have to resize the images in this approach and it would be faster.

**EDIT**

I tried this in Matlab using some sample images provided in opencv samples:

```
im1 = imread('baboon.jpg');
im2 = imread('board.jpg');
im3 = imread('fruits.jpg');
im4 = imread('fruits - small.jpg'); % fruits.jpg scaled down 25% using mspaint

% using grayscale for simplicity
gr1 = rgb2gray(im1);
gr2 = rgb2gray(im2);
gr3 = rgb2gray(im3);
gr4 = rgb2gray(im4);

[cnt_baboon, x] = imhist(gr1);
[cnt_board, x] = imhist(gr2);
[cnt_fruits, x] = imhist(gr3);
[cnt_fruits_small, x] = imhist(gr4);

% X: not normalized
X = [cnt_baboon cnt_board cnt_fruits cnt_fruits_small];
H = X'*X;
N = sqrt(diag(H)*diag(H)');
% normalize. this would be faster
G = H./N
```

The resulting G matrix:

G =

```
1.0000    0.8460    0.7748    0.7729
0.8460    1.0000    0.8741    0.8686
0.7748    0.8741    1.0000    0.9947
0.7729    0.8686    0.9947    1.0000
```

You can see that G(3,4) (and G(4,3)) are very close to 1.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for histogram matching. There are inbuilt functions for histogram matching, for example bhattacharya distance etc, and they don't require both of your images to be of same size also.

Just check this link on opencv site,
[link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html)